# How to use extend/override "jquery.inputmask" to validate date in mm/dd format

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I want to alter existing `query.inputmask` `alias` present for `mm/dd/yyyy` format in `inputmask` and create a new one that includes validation for `mm/dd` format as well. Checked the below link but could not figure out how. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

To make the long story short, I want to achieve something like this, as explained below.

Currently what works (existing alias):-

```
$("._input_selector").inputmask({
    alias : 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
```

What I want to do (custom alias/my own TODO):-

```
$("._input_selector").inputmask({
    alias : 'mm/dd'
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39456981/5086633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try code below:

```js
   var maskConfig = {
    mask: "1/2",
    leapday: "29-02-",
    separator: "/",
    alias: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    placeholder: "mm/dd"
};

$("._input_selector").inputmask("mm/dd/yyyy", maskConfig);
```

```html
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
  
  <input id="input-mask" name="input-mask" class="_input_selector" type="text"  />
```

Comment: Brilliant. How can I get the documentation for inputmask? when you made this custom config, what was on your mind. If you could elaborate that it would be great!